# Animate tableView for future/past months

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a project that uses a simple UITableView to represent a month of items.  Each row is a day of the month and the table represents a single month.  There is a small view at the top of the table view with buttons to move forward in time (Next) and backwards in time (Prev), one month per click.  This all works perfectly fine.

[image: Table view for November 2020]

What I am searching for is a way to "slide" the current month off and the next/previous month on when the appropriate buttons are clicked.  The affect would be similar to using a page view, but there could be "infinite" (indeterminate) number of months forward/backward, so this seems to eliminate using segues, page views, etc.

I have found code to animate the left/right movement of the current tableview, but these don't seem to fit the bill either: I need a "new" table view to move into view as the "old" table view moves off.

The only thing that seems to make sense is:

1. Create a new table view "offscreen" and populate it
2. Animate the current table view to  move off screen as the new table view is animated moving on screen
3. Swap "old" and "new" to prepare for the next transition

Seems like a ton of work, which I guess is OK but I'd hate to invest the time if there is a better way. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [UITableViewDiffableDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource). It's able to animate changes and it's customizable.

Comment: @vadian this looks very promising!  Thanks!

Comment: Figuring this out too a few minutes, but once I did and applied it to my project the results were quite satisfying!  Thanks again!